# Embedded - Vincluum-II - Why does vos_dev_ioctl function freeze?

Tags: embedded, usb, ftdi

So I'm using the Vinculum-II microcontroller to build a simple USB application but I'm kinda stuck. I downloaded a reference project from http://www.ftdichip.com/Firmware/Precompiled/HIDUART.zip and want to modify this in order to make my project (which is a basic USB converter) happen.
The project compiles and flashes succesfully, however when I try running it, it does not detect anything, nor any information is sent via UART. I tried debugging it, and after the HID (mouse) is detected, the software crashes when it enters the following function: vos_dev_ioctl(hUSBHOST_1, &hc_iocb);

I tried some other examples from the book (http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/TechnicalPublications/USBDesignByExample.htm[2] (chapter 9, stage 2)) which work, but as soon as I modify the code the slightest bit (renaming and adding a parameter to a function which is not used), which does not have anything to do with the functionality, it crashes. The function where the code freezes are VOS specific functions (vos_lock_mutex / vos_dev_ioctl/ etc ..). The VOS seems to wait for something to resume from that function, but that thing that it's waiting for, never comes. The system gets stuck in the idle task.

Comment: Honestly, forward this thing to bin and forget about it. I have experience, and very bad at that, with this. Even it's example programs fail, I don't mean outright, but once you run in troubles, and try to observe the example programs, you will discover they reproduce the same. I inherited a code base of a project on this whose previous owner was fired. Decomposing, and piece by piece testing things trying to rebuild from scratch the entire mess I even ended up with a source file where I marked five proven compiler / RTOS / CPU bugs or quirks I had to work around.

Comment: After some fierce debugging, I finally got it to work. It seems that the example programs were at the limit of the stack usage. As soon as you added something, even a parameter to a function that doesn't do anything, you would run into a stack overflow. However it seems peculiar that a program that outputs some stuff on the terminal would use so much stack. I don't know if this is a static problem (the stack overflows because of the program's memory usage) or a dynamic behavior (the stack usage gets bigger and bigger due to a memory leak somewhere, even in the RTOS). I hope it's the first one.

Comment: If you can (it was 2 years ago, so I don't remember much) try to add stack canaries to help yourself identifying the problem when it happens. You declare, say, a 16 byte array just above the stack, fill it up with some "magic" pattern at boot, and preiodically check it, outputting some indication of failure (such as turning a LED on) if the pattern is destroyed. If you keep being on the edge of your stack, this will help a lot!

Comment: Good tip. I caught the error, by checking out the thread manager. Once, i called a serial "printf"function, and instead of seeing the contents on the UART interface, I saw it as the name of a task in the thread manager in the debugger. That led me to the idea that it was a stack issue. I doubled the stack for that thread, and no problemos. The issue with their boards is there is no support whatsoever. No forums, 50 page manual for the whole OS. It could be a powerful board, but they destroyed it with the lack of documentation and support imo.

Comment: Could be if only it worked. However the alternatives are neither easy: after I proved what they want is not solveable in a reasonable time on this, since I was needed for a more important project, they passed it down to an other guy to start it over with 32 bit PIC. Half year later I got invited to "crack" GCC (XC32) so it would size-optimize his USB mess of 3rd party libs to be crammed in the micro's flash, still the most popular article on my site...